Structure of the Solana block
I cannot understand how the JSON Solana blocks are structured, received, from https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com rpc:

Why are zero indexes of pre and post Balances different, but any other are rather not, are they not filled?

Where can I find addresses of wallets, that are sending transactions, in given block, together with the amounts and addresses, they are sending the transactions to?


===========================================================================
{
  computeUnitsConsumed: 2100,
  err: null,
  fee: 5000,
  innerInstructions: [],
  loadedAddresses: { readonly: [], writable: [] },
  logMessages: [
    'Program Vote111111111111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]',
    'Program Vote111111111111111111111111111111111111111 success'
  ],
  postBalances: [ 13721073429, 5099782134, 1 ],
  postTokenBalances: [],
  preBalances: [ 13721078429, 5099782134, 1 ],
  preTokenBalances: [],
  rewards: [],
  status: { Ok: null }
}
===========================================================================
{
  computeUnitsConsumed: 2100,
  err: null,
  fee: 5000,
  innerInstructions: [],
  loadedAddresses: { readonly: [], writable: [] },
  logMessages: [
    'Program Vote111111111111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]',
    'Program Vote111111111111111111111111111111111111111 success'
  ],
  postBalances: [ 3589844594, 301225635, 1 ],
  postTokenBalances: [],
  preBalances: [ 3589849594, 301225635, 1 ],
  preTokenBalances: [],
  rewards: [],
  status: { Ok: null }
}
===========================================================================
{
  computeUnitsConsumed: 2100,
  err: null,
  fee: 5000,
  innerInstructions: [],
  loadedAddresses: { readonly: [], writable: [] },
  logMessages: [
    'Program Vote111111111111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]',
    'Program Vote111111111111111111111111111111111111111 success'
  ],
  postBalances: [ 7991584466, 22555840592, 1 ],
  postTokenBalances: [],
  preBalances: [ 7991589466, 22555840592, 1 ],
  preTokenBalances: [],
  rewards: [],
  status: { Ok: null }
}
===========================================================================
{
  computeUnitsConsumed: 2100,
  err: null,
  fee: 5000,
  innerInstructions: [],
  loadedAddresses: { readonly: [], writable: [] },
  logMessages: [
    'Program Vote111111111111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]',
    'Program Vote111111111111111111111111111111111111111 success'
  ],
  postBalances: [ 7076581368, 7095278979, 1 ],
  postTokenBalances: [],
  preBalances: [ 7076586368, 7095278979, 1 ],
  preTokenBalances: [],
  rewards: [],
  status: { Ok: null }
}
===========================================================================
{
  computeUnitsConsumed: 2100,
  err: null,
  fee: 5000,
  innerInstructions: [],
  loadedAddresses: { readonly: [], writable: [] },
  logMessages: [
    'Program Vote111111111111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]',
    'Program Vote111111111111111111111111111111111111111 success'
  ],
  postBalances: [ 334981050135, 17320043861, 1 ],
  postTokenBalances: [],
  preBalances: [ 334981055135, 17320043861, 1 ],
  preTokenBalances: [],
  rewards: [],
  status: { Ok: null }
}
===========================================================================
{
  computeUnitsConsumed: 2100,
  err: null,
  fee: 5000,
  innerInstructions: [],
  loadedAddresses: { readonly: [], writable: [] },
  logMessages: [
    'Program Vote111111111111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]',
    'Program Vote111111111111111111111111111111111111111 success'
  ],
  postBalances: [ 3862309880, 30000739, 1 ],
  postTokenBalances: [],
  preBalances: [ 3862314880, 30000739, 1 ],
  preTokenBalances: [],
  rewards: [],
  status: { Ok: null }
}
===========================================================================
{
  computeUnitsConsumed: 2100,
  err: null,
  fee: 5000,
  innerInstructions: [],
  loadedAddresses: { readonly: [], writable: [] },
  logMessages: [
    'Program Vote111111111111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]',
    'Program Vote111111111111111111111111111111111111111 success'
  ],
  postBalances: [ 5656360796, 28012091552, 1 ],
  postTokenBalances: [],
  preBalances: [ 5656365796, 28012091552, 1 ],
  preTokenBalances: [],
  rewards: [],
  status: { Ok: null }
}
===========================================================================
{
  computeUnitsConsumed: 2100,
  err: null,
  fee: 5000,
  innerInstructions: [],
  loadedAddresses: { readonly: [], writable: [] },
  logMessages: [
    'Program Vote111111111111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]',
    'Program Vote111111111111111111111111111111111111111 success'
  ],
  postBalances: [ 32452528157, 11099764212, 1 ],
  postTokenBalances: [],
  preBalances: [ 32452533157, 11099764212, 1 ],
  preTokenBalances: [],
  rewards: [],
  status: { Ok: null }
}
===========================================================================
{
  computeUnitsConsumed: 2100,
  err: null,
  fee: 5000,
  innerInstructions: [],
  loadedAddresses: { readonly: [], writable: [] },
  logMessages: [
    'Program Vote111111111111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]',
    'Program Vote111111111111111111111111111111111111111 success'
  ],
  postBalances: [ 3743229248, 27074500, 1 ],
  postTokenBalances: [],
  preBalances: [ 3743234248, 27074500, 1 ],
  preTokenBalances: [],
  rewards: [],
  status: { Ok: null }
}
===========================================================================
{
  computeUnitsConsumed: 2100,
  err: null,
  fee: 5000,
  innerInstructions: [],
  loadedAddresses: { readonly: [], writable: [] },
  logMessages: [
    'Program Vote111111111111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]',
    'Program Vote111111111111111111111111111111111111111 success'
  ],
  postBalances: [ 54000944721, 3694950660, 1 ],
  postTokenBalances: [],
  preBalances: [ 54000949721, 3694950660, 1 ],
  preTokenBalances: [],
  rewards: [],
  status: { Ok: null }
}
===========================================================================
{
  computeUnitsConsumed: 2100,
  err: null,
  fee: 5000,
  innerInstructions: [],
  loadedAddresses: { readonly: [], writable: [] },
  logMessages: [
    'Program Vote111111111111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]',
    'Program Vote111111111111111111111111111111111111111 success'
  ],
  postBalances: [ 19336011031, 286183681334, 1 ],
  postTokenBalances: [],
  preBalances: [ 19336016031, 286183681334, 1 ],
  preTokenBalances: [],
  rewards: [],
  status: { Ok: null }
}
===========================================================================
{
  computeUnitsConsumed: 2100,
  err: null,
  fee: 5000,
  innerInstructions: [],
  loadedAddresses: { readonly: [], writable: [] },
  logMessages: [
    'Program Vote111111111111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]',
    'Program Vote111111111111111111111111111111111111111 success'
  ],
  postBalances: [ 341110604891, 27074401, 1 ],
  postTokenBalances: [],
  preBalances: [ 341110609891, 27074401, 1 ],
  preTokenBalances: [],
  rewards: [],
  status: { Ok: null }
}
===========================================================================
{
  computeUnitsConsumed: 2100,
  err: null,
  fee: 5000,
  innerInstructions: [],
  loadedAddresses: { readonly: [], writable: [] },
  logMessages: [
    'Program Vote111111111111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]',
    'Program Vote111111111111111111111111111111111111111 success'
  ],
  postBalances: [ 41771057605, 3505768223984, 1 ],
  postTokenBalances: [],
  preBalances: [ 41771062605, 3505768223984, 1 ],
  preTokenBalances: [],
  rewards: [],
  status: { Ok: null }
}
===========================================================================
{
  computeUnitsConsumed: 2100,
  err: null,
  fee: 5000,
  innerInstructions: [],
  loadedAddresses: { readonly: [], writable: [] },
  logMessages: [
    'Program Vote111111111111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]',
    'Program Vote111111111111111111111111111111111111111 success'
  ],
  postBalances: [ 985604521180, 11441555676307, 1 ],
  postTokenBalances: [],
  preBalances: [ 985604526180, 11441555676307, 1 ],
  preTokenBalances: [],
  rewards: [],
  status: { Ok: null }
}
===========================================================================
{
  computeUnitsConsumed: 2100,
  err: null,
  fee: 5000,
  innerInstructions: [],
  loadedAddresses: { readonly: [], writable: [] },
  logMessages: [
    'Program Vote111111111111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]',
    'Program Vote111111111111111111111111111111111111111 success'
  ],
  postBalances: [ 20612048457, 38516338523, 1 ],
  postTokenBalances: [],
  preBalances: [ 20612053457, 38516338523, 1 ],
  preTokenBalances: [],
  rewards: [],
  status: { Ok: null }
}
===========================================================================
{
  computeUnitsConsumed: 120971,
  err: null,
  fee: 5001,
  innerInstructions: [ { index: 1, instructions: [Array] } ],
  loadedAddresses: {
    readonly: [
      'GAMEzqJehF8yAnKiTARUuhZMvLvkZVAsCVri5vSfemLr',
      '23MZ2crHoWKJ6rvZz8B7fEJchvFNHcq6HMBrFabEksrK',
      'C2478tbSLC1gfcDuCyr4pv66QQiybn77EiR1a4k7htT5',
      'CSTatsVpHbvZmwHbCjZKVfYQT5JXfsXccXufhEcwCqTg',
      'DataJpxFgHhzwu4zYJeHCnAv21YqWtanEBphNxXBHdEY',
      'BApwmntmNTntNZBBqe2AbaUzywegoq6nsdcApjWvnPUR',
      'XPneyd1Wvoay3aAa24QiKyPjs8SUbZnGg5xvpKvTgN9',
      'AdEhYz4LGdekRxbpXEX6QGJL6cH1bjBC5mN4s2aXZWSV',
      'Cr3rdBxK1MP7ggze2TvTHsusVjhoaAiHjrfARDwZXLYL',
      'Cargo2VNTPPTi9c1vq1Jw5d3BWUNr18MjRtSupAghKEk',
      'TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA',
      'Sysvar1nstructions1111111111111111111111111',
      'SysvarS1otHashes111111111111111111111111111',
      'BNTH5DWDPWsHsSQVscqJVe2GQKnQcAmPt4BLRPMGPfHu',
      'GYFk8mgxw2M8uWLrL1hCfYDMLfAZLDH2VEzcrBoJwgue'
    ],
    writable: [ 'foodQJAztMzX1DKpLaiounNe2BDMds5RNuPC6jsNrDG' ]
  },
  logMessages: [
    'Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]',
    'Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 success',
    'Program SAGE2HAwep459SNq61LHvjxPk4pLPEJLoMETef7f7EE invoke [1]',
    'Program log: Instruction: ScanForSurveyDataUnits',
    'Program log: Sector: [-3, 8]',
    'Program log: SDU probability: 0.10661802257872656',
    'Program Point2iBvz7j5TMVef8nEgpmz4pDr7tU7v3RjAfkQbM invoke [2]',
    'Program log: Instruction: IncrementPoints',
    'Program log: old daily_points >> 10000 | old earned_points >> 1577388 | points input >> 2 | points_to_add >> 0 | new daily_points >> 10000 | new earned_points >> 1577388 | global limit >> 100000000000000',
    'Program Point2iBvz7j5TMVef8nEgpmz4pDr7tU7v3RjAfkQbM consumed 9120 of 103108 compute units',
    'Program Point2iBvz7j5TMVef8nEgpmz4pDr7tU7v3RjAfkQbM success',
    'Program Point2iBvz7j5TMVef8nEgpmz4pDr7tU7v3RjAfkQbM invoke [2]',
    'Program log: Instruction: IncrementPoints',
    'Program log: old daily_points >> 40000 | old earned_points >> 6274913 | points input >> 2 | points_to_add >> 0 | new daily_points >> 40000 | new earned_points >> 6274913 | global limit >> 100000000000000',
    'Program Point2iBvz7j5TMVef8nEgpmz4pDr7tU7v3RjAfkQbM consumed 9272 of 90420 compute units',
    'Program Point2iBvz7j5TMVef8nEgpmz4pDr7tU7v3RjAfkQbM success',
    'Program SAGE2HAwep459SNq61LHvjxPk4pLPEJLoMETef7f7EE consumed 120821 of 199850 compute units',
    'Program SAGE2HAwep459SNq61LHvjxPk4pLPEJLoMETef7f7EE success'
  ],
  postBalances: [
    106258994,   4621440,   1712160,
      2115840,   2039280,   2039280,
      2039280,   1642560,   1642560,
            1,   1141440,   2213280,
      1190160,  16112400,   1141440,
      1461600,   7231440,   2672640,
            0,   1426800,   1837440,
      1190160,  12277440,   1190160,
      1802640,   1141440, 934087680,
            0, 143487360,   1712160,
      1712160
  ],
  postTokenBalances: [
    {
      accountIndex: 4,
      mint: 'SDUsgfSZaDhhZ76U3ZgvtFiXsfnHbf2VrzYxjBZ5YbM',
      owner: 'C2478tbSLC1gfcDuCyr4pv66QQiybn77EiR1a4k7htT5',
      programId: 'TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA',
      uiTokenAmount: [Object]
    },
    {
      accountIndex: 5,
      mint: 'SDUsgfSZaDhhZ76U3ZgvtFiXsfnHbf2VrzYxjBZ5YbM',
      owner: '9zcdrjud6vZwTqqVtphdz3zqkW2emxLdBtyaz2BM2W4D',
      programId: 'TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA',
      uiTokenAmount: [Object]
    },
    {
      accountIndex: 6,
      mint: 'foodQJAztMzX1DKpLaiounNe2BDMds5RNuPC6jsNrDG',
      owner: '9zcdrjud6vZwTqqVtphdz3zqkW2emxLdBtyaz2BM2W4D',
      programId: 'TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA',
      uiTokenAmount: [Object]
    }
  ],
  preBalances: [
    106263995,   4621440,   1712160,
      2115840,   2039280,   2039280,
      2039280,   1642560,   1642560,
            1,   1141440,   2213280,
      1190160,  16112400,   1141440,
      1461600,   7231440,   2672640,
            0,   1426800,   1837440,
      1190160,  12277440,   1190160,
      1802640,   1141440, 934087680,
            0, 143487360,   1712160,
      1712160
  ],
  preTokenBalances: [
    {
      accountIndex: 4,
      mint: 'SDUsgfSZaDhhZ76U3ZgvtFiXsfnHbf2VrzYxjBZ5YbM',
      owner: 'C2478tbSLC1gfcDuCyr4pv66QQiybn77EiR1a4k7htT5',
      programId: 'TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA',
      uiTokenAmount: [Object]
    },
    {
      accountIndex: 5,
      mint: 'SDUsgfSZaDhhZ76U3ZgvtFiXsfnHbf2VrzYxjBZ5YbM',
      owner: '9zcdrjud6vZwTqqVtphdz3zqkW2emxLdBtyaz2BM2W4D',
      programId: 'TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA',
      uiTokenAmount: [Object]
    },
    {
      accountIndex: 6,
      mint: 'foodQJAztMzX1DKpLaiounNe2BDMds5RNuPC6jsNrDG',
      owner: '9zcdrjud6vZwTqqVtphdz3zqkW2emxLdBtyaz2BM2W4D',
      programId: 'TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA',
      uiTokenAmount: [Object]
    }
  ],
  rewards: [],
  status: { Ok: null }
}
===========================================================================
{
  computeUnitsConsumed: 85147,
  err: null,
  fee: 10010,
  innerInstructions: [
    { index: 3, instructions: [Array] },
    { index: 4, instructions: [Array] }
  ],
  loadedAddresses: { readonly: [], writable: [] },
  logMessages: [
    'Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]',
    'Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 success',
    'Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]',
    'Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 success',
    'Program GDDMwNyyx8uB6zrqwBFHjLLG3TBYk2F8Az4yrQC5RzMp invoke [1]',
    'Program log: Sequence in order | sequence_num=1725826030119 | last_known=1725826029618',
    'Program GDDMwNyyx8uB6zrqwBFHjLLG3TBYk2F8Az4yrQC5RzMp consumed 3504 of 105700 compute units',
    'Program GDDMwNyyx8uB6zrqwBFHjLLG3TBYk2F8Az4yrQC5RzMp success',
    'Program PhoeNiXZ8ByJGLkxNfZRnkUfjvmuYqLR89jjFHGqdXY invoke [1]',
    'Program log: Discriminant for phoenix::program::accounts::MarketHeader is 8167313896524341111',
    'Program log: PhoenixInstruction::CancelAllOrdersWithFreeFunds',
    'Program consumption: 98337 units remaining',
    'Program consumption: 77738 units remaining',
    'Program log: Sending batch 1 with header and 12 market events, total events sent: 12',
    'Program PhoeNiXZ8ByJGLkxNfZRnkUfjvmuYqLR89jjFHGqdXY invoke [2]',
    'Program PhoeNiXZ8ByJGLkxNfZRnkUfjvmuYqLR89jjFHGqdXY consumed 582 of 75318 compute units',
    'Program PhoeNiXZ8ByJGLkxNfZRnkUfjvmuYqLR89jjFHGqdXY success',
    'Program PhoeNiXZ8ByJGLkxNfZRnkUfjvmuYqLR89jjFHGqdXY consumed 27828 of 102196 compute units',
    'Program PhoeNiXZ8ByJGLkxNfZRnkUfjvmuYqLR89jjFHGqdXY success',
    'Program PhoeNiXZ8ByJGLkxNfZRnkUfjvmuYqLR89jjFHGqdXY invoke [1]',
    'Program log: Discriminant for phoenix::program::accounts::MarketHeader is 8167313896524341111',
    'Program log: PhoenixInstruction::PlaceMultiplePostOnlyOrders',
    'Program log: Discriminant for phoenix::program::accounts::Seat is 2002603505298356104',
    'Program log: Sending batch 1 with header and 24 market events, total events sent: 24',
    'Program PhoeNiXZ8ByJGLkxNfZRnkUfjvmuYqLR89jjFHGqdXY invoke [2]',
    'Program PhoeNiXZ8ByJGLkxNfZRnkUfjvmuYqLR89jjFHGqdXY consumed 582 of 22432 compute units',
    'Program PhoeNiXZ8ByJGLkxNfZRnkUfjvmuYqLR89jjFHGqdXY success',
    'Program PhoeNiXZ8ByJGLkxNfZRnkUfjvmuYqLR89jjFHGqdXY consumed 53515 of 74368 compute units',
    'Program return: PhoeNiXZ8ByJGLkxNfZRnkUfjvmuYqLR89jjFHGqdXY DAAAAHD2AQAAAAAAs8R+9P////9j9gEAAAAAALLEfvT/////VvYBAAAAAACxxH70/////0v2AQAAAAAAsMR+9P////9A9gEAAAAAAK/EfvT/////N/YBAAAAAACuxH70/////3P2AQAAAAAAUjuBCwAAAAB/9gEAAAAAAFM7gQsAAAAAjfYBAAAAAABUO4ELAAAAAJj2AQAAAAAAVTuBCwAAAACi9gEAAAAAAFY7gQsAAAAArPYBAAAAAABXO4ELAAAAAA==',
    'Program PhoeNiXZ8ByJGLkxNfZRnkUfjvmuYqLR89jjFHGqdXY success'
  ],
  postBalances: [
    31987182309,       2039280,
        1224960, 1716030039280,
        2039280,       2039280,
     1619397120,             1,
        1141440,     934087680,
              0,       1781760,
        1141440
  ],
  postTokenBalances: [
    {
      accountIndex: 1,
      mint: 'EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v',
      owner: 'c5uFC9XgDruz6XL2r8uPLLBSCQe5gngK4hmBvALYswD',
      programId: 'TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA',
      uiTokenAmount: [Object]
    },
    {
      accountIndex: 3,
      mint: 'So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112',
      owner: 'DkX6Zq912oMXhCDcgJdvgbBU5Jvd4B884VecYczCWuHu',
      programId: 'TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA',
      uiTokenAmount: [Object]
    },
    {
      accountIndex: 4,
      mint: 'So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112',
      owner: 'xx3nK3x3MCpYxgZsgRQPFoucfewJhFk2EUqysgQ9hAm',
      programId: 'TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA',
      uiTokenAmount: [Object]
    },
    {
      accountIndex: 5,
      mint: 'EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v',
      owner: 'xx3nK3x3MCpYxgZsgRQPFoucfewJhFk2EUqysgQ9hAm',
      programId: 'TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA',
      uiTokenAmount: [Object]
    }
  ],
  preBalances: [
    31987192319,       2039280,
        1224960, 1716030039280,
        2039280,       2039280,
     1619397120,             1,
        1141440,     934087680,
              0,       1781760,
        1141440
  ],
  preTokenBalances: [
    {
      accountIndex: 1,
      mint: 'EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v',
      owner: 'c5uFC9XgDruz6XL2r8uPLLBSCQe5gngK4hmBvALYswD',
      programId: 'TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA',
      uiTokenAmount: [Object]
    },
    {
      accountIndex: 3,
      mint: 'So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112',
      owner: 'DkX6Zq912oMXhCDcgJdvgbBU5Jvd4B884VecYczCWuHu',
      programId: 'TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA',
      uiTokenAmount: [Object]
    },
    {
      accountIndex: 4,
      mint: 'So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112',
      owner: 'xx3nK3x3MCpYxgZsgRQPFoucfewJhFk2EUqysgQ9hAm',
      programId: 'TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA',
      uiTokenAmount: [Object]
    },
    {
      accountIndex: 5,
      mint: 'EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v',
      owner: 'xx3nK3x3MCpYxgZsgRQPFoucfewJhFk2EUqysgQ9hAm',
      programId: 'TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA',
      uiTokenAmount: [Object]
    }
  ],
  returnData: {
    data: [
      'DAAAAHD2AQAAAAAAs8R+9P////9j9gEAAAAAALLEfvT/////VvYBAAAAAACxxH70/////0v2AQAAAAAAsMR+9P////9A9gEAAAAAAK/EfvT/////N/YBAAAAAACuxH70/////3P2AQAAAAAAUjuBCwAAAAB/9gEAAAAAAFM7gQsAAAAAjfYBAAAAAABUO4ELAAAAAJj2AQAAAAAAVTuBCwAAAACi9gEAAAAAAFY7gQsAAAAArPYBAAAAAABXO4ELAAAAAA==',
      'base64'
    ],
    programId: 'PhoeNiXZ8ByJGLkxNfZRnkUfjvmuYqLR89jjFHGqdXY'
  },
  rewards: [],
  status: { Ok: null }
}
===========================================================================
{
  computeUnitsConsumed: 14415,
  err: { InstructionError: [ 2, [Object] ] },
  fee: 7001,
  innerInstructions: [],
  loadedAddresses: {
    readonly: [
      'TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA',
      'ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL',
      '11111111111111111111111111111111',
      '675kPX9MHTjS2zt1qfr1NYHuzeLXfQM9H24wFSUt1Mp8',
      '5Q544fKrFoe6tsEbD7S8EmxGTJYAKtTVhAW5Q5pge4j1'
    ],
    writable: []
  },
  logMessages: [
    'Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]',
    'Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 success',
    'Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]',
    'Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 success',
    'Program 5YBiKeEKz9PrDcdLkdQL89gVW7re3S3KVpUcbEhHBigz invoke [1]',
    'Program log: Instruction: SwapOut',
    'Program log: AnchorError thrown in programs/eater/src/instructions/swap_out.rs:54. Error Code: AlreadyInUse. Error Number: 6010. Error Message: already in use.',
    'Program 5YBiKeEKz9PrDcdLkdQL89gVW7re3S3KVpUcbEhHBigz consumed 14115 of 199700 compute units',
    'Program 5YBiKeEKz9PrDcdLkdQL89gVW7re3S3KVpUcbEhHBigz failed: custom program error: 0x177a'
  ],
  postBalances: [
     80555583521,  46247532757,
         2039280, 133017828243,
         1621680,      6125100,
    635909229001,      2039580,
         2039280,            1,
         1398960,    934087680,
       731913600,            1,
         1141440,   4290899037
  ],
  postTokenBalances: [
    {
      accountIndex: 2,
      mint: 'BSqMUYb6ePwKsby85zrXaDa4SNf6AgZ9YfA2c4mZpump',
      owner: 'BmanDqQELF7QY5uRPw8vg3eMjR74WZnszKmNbLJKkay3',
      programId: 'TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA',
      uiTokenAmount: [Object]
    },
    {
      accountIndex: 3,
      mint: 'So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112',
      owner: 'BmanDqQELF7QY5uRPw8vg3eMjR74WZnszKmNbLJKkay3',
      programId: 'TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA',
      uiTokenAmount: [Object]
    },
    {
      accountIndex: 6,
      mint: 'So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112',
      owner: '5Q544fKrFoe6tsEbD7S8EmxGTJYAKtTVhAW5Q5pge4j1',
      programId: 'TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA',
      uiTokenAmount: [Object]
    },
    {
      accountIndex: 7,
      mint: 'BSqMUYb6ePwKsby85zrXaDa4SNf6AgZ9YfA2c4mZpump',
      owner: '5Q544fKrFoe6tsEbD7S8EmxGTJYAKtTVhAW5Q5pge4j1',
      programId: 'TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA',
      uiTokenAmount: [Object]
    },
    {
      accountIndex: 8,
      mint: 'BSqMUYb6ePwKsby85zrXaDa4SNf6AgZ9YfA2c4mZpump',
      owner: '6g3WrugW7wunvVDsp5in6Yjm1ugNWpB7F9AoSnj5Tie7',
      programId: 'TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA',
      uiTokenAmount: [Object]
    }
  ],
  preBalances: [
     80555590522,  46247532757,
         2039280, 133017828243,
         1621680,      6125100,
    635909229001,      2039580,
         2039280,            1,
         1398960,    934087680,
       731913600,            1,
         1141440,   4290899037
  ],
  preTokenBalances: [
    {
      accountIndex: 2,
      mint: 'BSqMUYb6ePwKsby85zrXaDa4SNf6AgZ9YfA2c4mZpump',
      owner: 'BmanDqQELF7QY5uRPw8vg3eMjR74WZnszKmNbLJKkay3',
      programId: 'TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA',
      uiTokenAmount: [Object]
    },
    {
      accountIndex: 3,
      mint: 'So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112',
      owner: 'BmanDqQELF7QY5uRPw8vg3eMjR74WZnszKmNbLJKkay3',
      programId: 'TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA',
      uiTokenAmount: [Object]
    },
    {
      accountIndex: 6,
      mint: 'So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112',
      owner: '5Q544fKrFoe6tsEbD7S8EmxGTJYAKtTVhAW5Q5pge4j1',
      programId: 'TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA',
      uiTokenAmount: [Object]
    },
    {
      accountIndex: 7,
      mint: 'BSqMUYb6ePwKsby85zrXaDa4SNf6AgZ9YfA2c4mZpump',
      owner: '5Q544fKrFoe6tsEbD7S8EmxGTJYAKtTVhAW5Q5pge4j1',
      programId: 'TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA',
      uiTokenAmount: [Object]
    },
    {
      accountIndex: 8,
      mint: 'BSqMUYb6ePwKsby85zrXaDa4SNf6AgZ9YfA2c4mZpump',
      owner: '6g3WrugW7wunvVDsp5in6Yjm1ugNWpB7F9AoSnj5Tie7',
      programId: 'TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA',
      uiTokenAmount: [Object]
    }
  ],
  rewards: [],
  status: { Err: { InstructionError: [Array] } }
}
===========================================================================




This just looks like the "meta" field of a returned transaction. Try looking at the transaction.message.accountKeys field for all the account keys: https://solana.com/docs/rpc/http/gettransaction, and then line them up with the pre / post balances

"Thanks a lot for your help! I have one more question about this transaction: https://solscan.io/tx/386V1f1ppLehnfu3fW1YC9JtgxWg1ZdHnvTJHhaRpaMGVrrWGaGMsrosX5NrJWLKE2qgPnQXEVswCXPGK5PrGMvN.
Why does it involve multiple accounts, and how does it process through all of them in one block only to end up in one or two accounts? It seems different from a bulk transaction. Can you explain this?"

I'm not sure what you mean by a "bulk transaction", but this transaction may look complicated because it involves "wrapped SOL", which puts native SOL into an SPL Token account, typically for trading. So in this case, it creates a wrapped SOL account, trades with it, then closes it. So although funds went in and out of that account, In the end, it nets out to 0, so only the SOL wallet and GOOSE SPL Token account actually see changes.

Thank you! If I may ask one more thing, how can I distinguish between regular transactions and transactions involving the purchase of new tokens or coins using the RPC response, I have come across, information, that instruction object in response, should cointain "swap" as value, if that's the case, but did not find single?

Sorry, I don't know too much about how trading applications structure their instructions. You should ask another question with more details about the issue you're seeing
